# Problem in Qing Han PDE book: Non-descreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I encountered a difficulty when proving the following function $N(r)$ is non-decreasing.

[image]

For non-decreasing function, I think that its derivative should be $\frac{d N(r)}{dr} > 0$.The following is the result of its derivative: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d N}{dr} = \frac{ \int_{B_{r}} |\nabla u|^{2} dx }{ \int_{ \partial{B}_{r}} u^{2} dS } 
+ r \left( \frac{ \int_{  \partial{B}_{r}} u^{2} dS \frac{d}{dr} \int_{B_{r}} |\nabla u|^{2} dx  - \int_{B_{r}} |\nabla u|^{2} dx \frac{d}{dr} \int_{  \partial{B}_{r}} u^{2} dS }{ (\int_{  \partial{B}_{r}} u^{2} dS)^{2}} \right)
\end{equation}
The difficulty that I encountered is that the derivative inside the big bracket as there is a minus sign there. Therefore,I cannot judge whether $\frac{d N}{dr} > 0$. Could anyone help me to solve my difficulty? Thank you.